# Validate and Format a postcode dynamically

Tags: javascript

I wanted to know if it was possible with JavaScript to validate a postcode **AND** format a postcode in the right format (if wrong format). So instead of asking the user to re-type the postcode in correct format, it does it automatically, if its validated correctly.

The format I need is for UK postcodes (no space) e.g.:

```
CB30AX
cb30AX
SG120JS
sg120js
```

So if the user types in a postcode like below, it gets converted:

```
CB3 0ax  --> CB30AX
cB3 0AX  --> CB30AX
SG12 0JS --> SG120JS
sg12 0js --> SG120JS
```

Can this be done? I have almost 0 knowledge of JS but I did have a look for a solution and could not find one which did what I needed it to do above.

I have also provided a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lm3hqsbo/1/)

Comment: var postCode = "CB3 0ax"; var formattedPostCode = postCod.replace(' ', '').toUpperCase();

Comment: @IgorSemin would you mind showing me in a fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lm3hqsbo/3/ - i update your fiddle

Comment: @IgorSemin I see, I'm going to try this live

Comment: @IgorSemin works PERFECTLY! Thank you so much. Add it in as an answer and I'll accept :)

Comment: If you also want validation you can add a regular expression and "test" it first, something like `/\w\w?\d\d?\w\s?\d\w\w/` could broadly work, but every rule described here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcodes_in_the_United_Kingdom could be encapsulated in a regular expression if you wanted to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var formattedPostCode = postCode.replace(/\s/g, '').toUpperCase()
```

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lm3hqsbo/3/)

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would you capitalize only the first letter?

Comment: charAt() + slice(). Example: var formattedPostCode = postCode.replace(/\s/g, ''); formattedPostCode.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + formattedPostCode.slice(1)

Comment: np, but use search - it's all already many times thought out and answered

Answer (score 0):

Just attach this to your input box - see fiddle

```
 format_pc = function(e){
    e.value = e.value.toUpperCase().replace(/\s/g, '');
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8h9o2qnx/